# Transform XML with publicly available XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't have much practical experience with XSLT so I would need your "best practice" help on the problem. XML is automaticaly generated and sent to the user (emails, etc.). This XML contains the following header element (starting and ending element tags are deleted due to editor problems):

```
xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://example.com/myvisualisation.xslt"
```

XSLT is uploaded and available at given URL.
What is the "standard/normal" way for user to open received XML with this transformation applied? (when I try with browser I get cross-domain error).
Is it possible (and how) to arrange things so that user can simply double click attached XML and he/she will see transformed document?

Also when I try to open XML with MS Excel (which gives me an option to apply transformation) is quite "messy" (missing borders, etc.) compared to if I use browser (looks ok) although I am using very standard and simple HTML.. no fancy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sending XML files to "users" is a good idea. Why don't you do the transformation for them and send them the resulting HTML file - or (preferably, IMHO) use some other generally accepted format such as PDF?

> Also when I try to open XML with MS Excel (which gives me an option to
>   apply transformation) is quite "messy" (missing borders, etc.)
>   compared to if I use browser (looks ok) although I am using very
>   standard and simple HTML.. no fancy stuff.

Hard to tell based on so little info (none, really) but it could have something to do with Excel not being a browser.

Comment: Basicly I send a package to the end user: PDF (my printed version) + XML (raw data for processing) + visualisation (of raw data). I have to follow some rules where it is required to also include XSLT visualisation. If I include it, or upload it somewhere to the web, user still can't just simply dbl click XML and see it transformed - or can he? ..this is what I am trying to figure.

Comment: @hpet The problem here is standardization. There is no universally accepted default application to open XML files (unlike HTML, for example, which you can assume will be opened in a browser on practically any system). And that's before the problem of browser security. I am not sure what your rules say, but since the end result of your "XSLT visualisation" process is an HTML document, I can see no reason why you couldn't just send that.

Comment: @hpet The other question here is what is a "user"? As a user myself, I do not expect anyone to send me XML files. As a "sophisticated user", I would expect you to send me both the XML and the XSLT files in the same package, and leave it to me to handle the transformation. Linking the XML file to the (local) XSLT would be a nice addition - in case I would want to open the XML in a browser. -- BTW, have you tried including links to **both** the local and the served stylesheet?

Comment: I can easly send XSLT in the same package. How do I make a local link? Just a file name? User can import XML file into application for processing and XSLT is for "quick" visualisation of data in that exact XML - therefore I wish to provide some "amateur user-friendly" way to visualize included XML. XML is signed and previewing with XSLT will show valid data - including HTML will not be the same (there is PDF included as alternative).

Comment: "*How do I make a local link?*" Assuming both XML and XSLT are in the same directory: `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myvisualisation.xslt"?>`. -- "*including HTML will not be the same*" Why not? The result of the transformation (you say) is HTML. The browser will display the same HTML the same way, no matter if the transformation was done "live" just now, or three days ago.

Comment: Yes, but included HTML can already ba altered (faked and included). running visualisation on signed included XML is more true I guess. I think at the end I will throw this out as by the current rules XSLT is  optional.

Comment: @hpet HTML cannot be signed?

Answer (score 0):

Although browsers support XSLT, in practice, most XSLT that generates HTML is run on the server or in offline batch processes -- not within the browser.  **If at all possible, run XSLT in the server or in an offline batch process rather than in the browser.**

If you have to transform XML in the browser, be aware of some serious limitations and issues:

1. XSLT 2.0 is not supported by any of the major browsers.
2. Browser security models differ in ways that affect XSLT processing. 
   This can be a major source of frustration in developing or
   distributing documents that rely on browser-based XSLT.

   - As you've already encountered, cross-domain restrictions can be an
     issue.
   - While Firefox will allow locally loaded XSLT files to run, Chrome
     will not; [Chrome requires that XSLT be loaded from a server](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70088).

**Note:** It is not a "header element" but a processing instruction.  You should be able to paste it into your question verbatim, and it should look like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://example.com/myvisualisation.xslt"?>
```

If your document instead actually does represent this as an element [***wrong***],

```
<xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://example.com/myvisualisation.xslt"/>
```

then the link to the XSLT will certainly fail.

**Final note:** Your XML-in-MS Excel question should be asked separately with substantially more detail added.

Comment: Sorry, didn't express my self correctly with this header/processing instruction. but yet, I have it right. PLease read the comment one post up for more details on what I am trying to accomplish. About Excel, my bad, it was just a side question of no big importance. Thing is that I thought that XML+XSLT are kind of more "plug&play" and simple to apply also localy (in non-server environment)-

Comment: There was a time when it looked like XSLT was to be as plug-and-play for styling XML in the browser as CSS is for styling HTML, but, alas, it's not turned out to be like that.