# Retain formatting tags from XML with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tags, formatting

I have to display an XML document using XSLT but I would like apply the `<p>` and `<i>` HTML tags from the original XML document. For example p tag from XML would create a new paragraph. What would be the best way to accomplish this? 
XML and XSLT code posted below.

Edit: clarified the original question

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tour.xsl"?>
<cars>
   <car>
      <description>
        <p><i>There is some text here</i> There is some more text here</p>
        <p>This should be another paragraph</p>
        <p>This is yet another paragraph</p>
      </description>
   </car>
</cars>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Title</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:value-of select="car"/><p/>       
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>`
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is there a way to apply those tags instead so that the text between "i" tags is written in italics and "p" tags start a new paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your template to copy over the `p` elements like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Title</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="/cars/car">
          <xsl:for-each select="description/p">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given your XML input, the above XSLT will produce this output:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p><i>There is some text here</i> There is some more text here
      </p>
      <p>This should be another paragraph</p>
      <p>This is yet another paragraph</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

### Update:

> I am trying to run in komodo's built in browser and ie.

You'd have to research komodo's XSLT capabilities.  Also, be aware of [challenges running XSLT in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25997892/290085); better to run on the server or in batch mode and only use the browser to display the results.

That said, the following XML file will open in IE 11 and be styled per the above XSLT sheet (named `tour.xml` and located in the same directory as the XML file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='tour.xsl'?>
<cars>
   <car>
      <description>
        <p><i>There is some text here</i> There is some more text here</p>
        <p>This should be another paragraph</p>
        <p>This is yet another paragraph</p>
      </description>
   </car>
</cars>
```

Here's a screenshot of the output in IE 11:

[image]

---

### Update 2

> I tried the template solution but it still returns unformatted text in
>   one line.

If IE 11 is given an XML file without a `xml-stylesheet` PI,

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='tour.xsl'?>
```

then it will display the XML in an outline form.

If IE 11 is given an XML file with a `xml-stylesheet` PI *and* it ***can*** find the XSLT file specified, it will apply the XSLT and display the results in the browser.  This result can be seen in the above screenshot (and is your desired result).

If IE 11 is given an XML file with a `xml-stylesheet` PI *and* it ***cannot*** find the XSLT file specified, it will display unformatted text in one line as you describe.

***Therefore, focus the search for your problem on the location and name of the XSLT file.***  Here is what happens when I intentionally force such behavior by renaming the XSLT file,

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='tour_CANNOT_FIND.xsl'?>
```

so that it cannot be found:

[image]

**Note**: Press <kbd>F-12</kbd> to reveal the console.

Then, if you click on the "Allow blocked content" button:

[image]

You see the diagnostic message that `tour_CANNOT_FIND.xsl` cannot be found.  **If you resolve the problem of IE not finding your XSLT file, you should then see the formatted results of your XSLT file in the browser.**

Comment: Tried both ways but formatting is not applied for some reason. Any other suggestions? I might be missing something else, sorry I'm new to XML.

Comment: Are you wanting to run XSLT in the browser or via a standalone processor?

Comment: I am trying to run in komodo's built in browser and ie

Comment: Thanks again for the replies. I tried the template solution but it still returns unformatted text in one line. The IE screenshot above is exactly what I am trying to achieve but after trying in both komodo and IE I get the unformatted text. If you have any possible solutions please post them.

Comment: Unformated text will occur when IE cannot find the XSLT file.  Answer updated with further details.

Comment: I don't think finding XSLT file is the issue, before posting my code, I deleted all of the loops and tables from XSLT to make the post shorter. When I run the file on my PC everything works and all the information is displayed correctly. The only issue is that the paragraph and italics tags from the original XML get ignored. I have two files with the same name in the same location, one with .XML extension and the other with .XSL. My XSL file is added as an href in the original XML.

Comment: Did you or did you not check the console for error messages as I advised ?    You're not being very methodical in your reporting of what is working and what is not.  I've shown you (1) how to fix your XSLT so that the original `p` and `i` elements are outputted and (2) how to check if there are any errors such as an inability to find the XSLT.   You need to very carefully follow each step and report deviations.  Rehashing your old, failed approach rather than carefully reporting results of my recommendation is unproductive.

Answer (score 0):

your actual question can be answered with a stylesheet like this, which uses `apply-templates`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Title</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/cars/car/description/*"/>
                <p/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, if you have multiple `cars` you probably want to have some headlines. Then a stylesheet like this may point towards that goal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Title</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/cars/car/*"/>
                <p/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="description">
        <h1>Subtitle</h1>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```